# Is there an eraser tool to get rid of sketch in Preview?

Tags: macbook, preview

I use Macbook Preview to add annotate and it annoys me that whenever use the freehand sketch tool in the tool bar to write something, I can't get rid of it. Am I missing something here?
[image]

For example, I want to get rid of the 10 since I sould have written 8 instead, but I can't! Doesn't seem to have the option here.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Undo, until the changes are committed.

Once committed - saved, or even just closed & re-opened - the annotation becomes a part of the image.
JPG has no layering capability, so once saved the image & your annotation become just a single layer, with no way to differentiate them. The part of the original image 'behind' the annotation no longer exists.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am not talking about Saved. I seem unable to get rid of my annotation even simply after just written it.